# Laravel Dusk screenshot

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I'm using laravel `5.6` and `Dusk` for running some tests.

I'm always taking my screenshot like this

```
...
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverDimension;
...
class LoginTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    public function testLogin()
    {
        $user = User::first();

        $this->browse(function ($browser) use ( $user ) {
            $test = $browser->visit( new Login)
                    ->resize(1920,1080)                    
                    ...                
                    ->driver->takeScreenshot(base_path('tests/Browser/screenshots/testLogin.png'));
        });
    }
}
```

But as my tests will be more and more used, I don't want to continue to write everytime `->resize(X,Y)` and `base_path('bla/blab/bla')`.

I wanted to define the **size** and **path** for every tests that will be written.

I guess I should define some function in `tests/DesukTestCase.php` but I'm not even aware of how I can retrieve the driver and so on.

Have you got some guidance or documentation about this? Because I can't find anything...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to add `'--window-size=1920,1080'` in `$options`. This will apply a 1920x1080 screen resolution to all your Dusk tests. Feel free to adjust to whatever window size you want.

So your DuskTestCase.php file should look like this:

```
protected function driver()
{
    $options = (new ChromeOptions())->addArguments([
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--headless',
        '--window-size=1920,1080',
    ]);

    $driver = RemoteWebDriver::create(
        'http://selenium:4444/wd/hub',
        DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
            ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY,
            $options
        )
    );

}
```

Answer (score 4):

In my `DuskTestCase` file I have the below in my `driver()` function.

```
protected function driver()
{
    $options = (new ChromeOptions())->addArguments([
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--headless',
    ]);

    $driver = RemoteWebDriver::create(
        'http://selenium:4444/wd/hub',
        DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
            ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY,
            $options
        )
    );

    $size = new WebDriverDimension(1280, 2000);
    $driver->manage()->window()->setSize($size);

    return $driver;
}
```

You should just be able to configure it with the right dimensions you need.

Comment: It's working fine, have you got any idea for my path issue?

Comment: The path of where to save it? I've only ever used the default location

Comment: By default it stored on the root of the application., no? Anyway, I'll figure it out later

Comment: In my case, screenshots get stored in `./tests/Browser/screenshots`

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the path issue, you can set it with `Browser::$storeScreenshotsAt` in `setUp` method of your test case class.

```
protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    Browser::$storeScreenshotsAt = '/path/to/your/screenshots';
}
```

Default location of `Browser::$storeScreenshotsAt` is set in [`setUp` method of the grand parent test case class](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/blob/master/src/TestCase.php#L27).
So, make sure that you set `Browser::$storeScreenshotsAt` after calling `parent::setUp()`, otherwise it will be overwritten by the default.