# Can't take screenshot in Laravel Dusk

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing, laravel-dusk

We are making a transition with our acceptance tests from Codeception to Laravel Dusk. Using laravel 5.6.

App is dockerized and we use a seperate selenium/standalone-chrome image.

When tests fail there are screenshots in tests/Browser/screenshots
but when I try taking them manually, they just don't work.
I tried taking them 2 ways:

```
$browser->screenshot('test');
$browser->driver->takeScreenshot(base_path('tests/Browser/screenshots/test2.png'));
```

With the same result. No errors and no screenshots in tests/Browser/screenshots.

Why could this happen?

Comment: this of any use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51613669/laravel-dusk-screenshot

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, but may interest you https://github.com/beyondcode/dusk-dashboard

Comment: Please show the full code of your Dusk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, problem was my code just didn't execute.

Reason was I named the function wrong

```
public function checkDashboard()
```

And turns out in dusk everything that doesn't start with "test" isn't executed. Just like in phpunit. But it doesn't says so in docs.
So after changing it to

```
public function testCheckDashboard()
```

my problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the captureFailuresFor() method:

```
protected function captureFailuresFor($browsers)
    {
        $browsers->each(function (Browser $browser, $key) {
          $body = $browser->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::tagName('body'));
            if (!empty($body)) {
                $currentSize = $body->getSize();
                $size = new WebDriverDimension($currentSize->getWidth(), $currentSize->getHeight());
                $browser->driver->manage()->window()->setSize($size);
            }
            $browser->screenshot('failure-'.$this->getName().'-'.$key);
        });
    }
```

Maybe this discussion could be helpful for you:
https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/320

Comment: I don't see how this would help. Failed screenshots work just fine problem is I can't take screenshot manually when I want.